# ARM Cortex-A9 banked registers

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm having a problem with banked register restoration.
Using GCC for the tool chain..
This is a xilinx zynq 7010, so the cpu is a cortex-a9

My understanding is that when in a privileged exception state (SVC,IRQ,FIQ etc..)
r0 points a a block of memory that has the machine state
and I execute:

```
ldm r0,{r0-r12,sp,lr,pc}^
```

Since this has the ^ at the end this should operate of the user/system registers, not the banked registers...Alas this does not seem to be the case.  (user sp and lr are not getting updated)

The following block of code does work however...

```
add r0,#52
ldm r0,{sp,lr}^ /* This works why doesn';'t it work in the previous statement */
nop
sub r0,#52  
ldr r1,[r0,#60]
mov lr,r1
ldm r0,{r0-r12} 
movs pc,lr
```

Trying to understand what I'm doing wrong, or what I misunderstood?